# how to redirect a url to a local folder on ubuntu desktop

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-gradle-plugin

I want my Android Studio to download Gradle file from a local folder instead of its site. 
for example, my folder is /home/user/gradle and site is https://services.gradle.org/distributions and both have gradle-3.5-all.zip

is there a way to redirect that site to a local folder?
I know I can change gradle-wrapper.properties file in gradle/wrapper folder but I have too many projects and I can't change it for all project.
also, my Gradle works in offline mode but for every project, the same Gradle version is downloading.

I should mention that my Android Studio and Gradle connect through an https proxy.

Comment: "I have too many projects and I can't change it for all project" -- write a script to change the `gradle-wrapper.properties` files. They are simply text files. I have several hundred projects, and I have a Ruby script for updating the Gradle and Android Plugin for Gradle versions on my development machine.

Answer (score 0):

put your file at /var/www/html/gradle-3.5-all.zip
and then

```
service apache2 start
```

then your file is at 127.0.0.1/gradle-3.5-all.zip

Comment: I don't want to change the path. In this case I should change all files to this address. Can I redirect https://services.gradle.org/distributions to 127.0.0.1 in host file?